# Meteor's Blaze keeps re-using first list element's attributes

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor 1.2.02 
 
I create a list with a helper:

```
<ul>
   {{#each movie}}
      <li id="{{_id}}">{{name}}</li>
   {{/each}}   
</ul>
```

The result:

```
<li id="1">Interstellar</i>
<li id="2">The Martian</i>
```

Then I hide Interstellar:

```
$("#1").hide();
```

Result:

```
<li id="1" style="display:none">Interstellar</li>
<li id="2">The Martian</li>
```

Then I remove Interstellar from the collection `Movies.remove({name: "Interstellar"})` and this is what I end up with after Blaze reactively updates the DOM:

```
<li id="2" style="display:none">The Martian</li>
```

Does anyone know why now "The Martian" is inside the list element with `display:none` that belonged to Interstellar? I thought Blaze would have removed that first `<li>` elements and all its attributes. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-blaze-animations/blob/master/client/main.coffee). Might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I've used `_uihooks` before but since this API is probably going to change soon, I was trying to avoid it on this project. I just think it's a strange behaviour that blaze is re-using the prior elements instead of re rendering the list. Maybe I'm missing something.